# Set TextBox Text In aspx File Using A C# Method

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2015

I want to set a TextBox Text in `aspx` file using a C# method.
Here is what I did :

**ASPX:**

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txt_btc_in_eth" runat="server" Text="<%# txt_btc_in_eth_val() %>" CssClass="only_decimal"></asp:TextBox>
```

**C# :**

```
protected string txt_btc_in_eth_val()
{
    string output = "0.02";
    return output;
}
```

But `txt_btc_in_eth_val()` never calls.
What is the problem?

---

**Edit 1:**
I also tried this html instead of server-side control :

```
<span><%# txt_btc_in_eth_val() %></span>
```

`txt_btc_in_eth_val()` never calls again.

---

**Edit 2:**
`<%=` instead of `<%#` does not work.

---

**Edit 3:**

```
public string txt_btc_in_eth_val()
{
    string output = "0.02";
    return output;
}
```

I changed `protected` to `public` > still does not work

Comment: Havent done aspx in a long time, but i believe to remember that %# was for databinding. try %=. however i would set a value of a textbox with txt_btc_in_eth.Text =  "mystring".

Comment: Use ‘<%=‘ instead <%#

Comment: Describe the error in question. Your method must be protected or public.

Comment: There is no error - txt_btc_in_eth_val() method does not call - I don't know why!? I put a brreakpoint during run & saw it never calls.

Comment: Try to use plain html input, instead of Asp TextBox server control. I remember that might be the problem. I have not used Asp.Net for 10 uears now, so I am guessing the answer. Server controls work with binding or setting value direct in code behind, as stated in first comment.

Comment: You could also use public property, instead of method, which makes code cleaner.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are you using WebForms in 2020? It's an obsolete, dead-end platform that doesn't work correctly with modern web-browsers.

Comment: This is an old project that i am changing it.

Comment: `<%# ` requires `DataBind()` method to be called. Does it work if you call `DataBind()` on `PageLoad` event?

Comment: Is there any replacement without `DataBind()` needed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should call DataBind() Method of that TextBox in Page_Load().

```
txt_btc_in_eth.DataBind();
```